# codeigniter can't access session data in another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to get data from database using session data as variable . The function is right I think, but it always give null as result. When I display it in view it gets nothing/`null`. Can anyone help me?

Im defining this code in `login` controller :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id_member', 'id_member');
```

function DataProfil in controller `c_perawat`

```
public function DataProfil(){
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id_member');
        $data['klinik']=$this->m_klinik->GetDataKlinik($session_id)->result();
        $data['sidebar']='member/perawat/sidebar';
        $data['content']='member/perawat/pr';
        $this->load->view('member/perawat/main',$data);

    }
```

My model function

```
public function GetDataKlinik($session_id){
        $klinik=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM klinik where id_perawat='$session_id'");
        return $klinik;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure with this?

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id_member', 'id_member');
```

The second parameter must be a value, maybe

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id_member', $id_member);
```

Comment: sama-sama :)  . Need to be more thorough

Answer (score 2):

Firstly make sure you have autoloaded the session under `application/config/autoload.php`

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Create an array `$session` variable before setting it to `session`

`$session_data = array('session_id' => $id);` //here you can add any number of session key and values.

Note: Here the `$id` is your `id` which you want to set the session.

Then set the `$session_data` to the session.

`$this->session->set_userdata('session_data',$session_data);`

To access the session variable

`$session_id = $this->session->userdata['session_data']['session_id'];`

To unset the session variable,

`$this->session->unset_userdata('session_data');`

Hope this helps you.